# AS3 Air for Android programatically show soft keyboard

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

Is there a way in AS3 Air for Android to show the soft keyboard programatically?

I have a project where when the user clicks a button, it pops up a form for them to enter their email address.  I have it set to programatically focus on the "TextInput", but unfortunately this doesn't automatically bring up the keyboard.  So the user has to tap the "TextInput" field again to bring up the keyboard.

Is there a way to just call a "show keyboard" function?  I tried adding:

```
email_txt.needsSoftKeyboard = true;
```

But that doesn't seem to help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Figured it out.  I just had to call requestSoftKeyboard(); on the TextInput component.

email_txt.requestSoftKeyboard();

Not sure why that was so hard to search for the answer.